CQRS + event sourcing + ddd - copying data between microservices
I am using CQRS and event-sourcing (Axon framework). I have microservices Warehouse and ConsumptionPrediction.
Warehouse allowes define filters for products (timestamp, product category, ...).
It is posible to query warehouse for filtered products by filterId. Ten thousands of product can be returned.
Use case is

Client (frontend) defines product filters in Warehouse microservice. ConsumptionPrediction holds only id of the filters.
ConsumptionPrediction contains aggregate PredictionDefinition that dispatches event PredisctionPrepared(FilterId startingPoint, FilterId endingPoint).
Now I need to start copying by query from Warehouse to ConsumptionPrediction. And for each product create an aggregate ProductPrediction.
The aggregate has got its own lifecycle.

My question is about copying - where and how to take place.
I have read that Saga/ProcessManager shouldn´t use queries. It should only coordinate flow - handle events and send commands.

I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly. Typically in an Axon application, the Warehouse microservice build op a projection, based on it's events. That projection can be queried by the ConsumerPrediction microservice, using some filter. I don't think you need to copy the data, but that depends on your requirements.
A Saga/ProcessManager is typically used to coordinate between domains, but I'm not sure that is the case here.

You understand. But I need the copy, because Aggregates in ConsumptionPrediction uses quantities of Warehouse products.
Aggregate ConsumptionPrediction contains fields startQuantity and endQuantity and algorithms working witch theese fealds.
Therefore, in my opinion, a copy is necessary.


My question is about copying - where and how to take place. I have read that Saga/ProcessManager shouldn´t use queries. It should only coordinate flow - handle events and send commands.

Not sure if I'd agree with that. Where did you read/hear that? If a component, any component, needs information it doesn't have for itself, it needs to perform a query to get it. That component may very well be a Saga/ProcessManager.
